# How to change python version of google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I know there are many similar questions already but it seems the situation of google colab is still changing.

I tried this [method](https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-change-python-version-from-default-35-to-38-of-google-colab/), but it's not working.

```
!apt-get install python3.8
!python3.8 --version
!ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python
```

I tried this method,

```
!wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.17/Python-3.8.17.tgz
!tar xvfz Python-3.8.17.tgz
!Python-3.8.17/configure
!make
!sudo make install
```

When I type `!python --version` it shows me python 3.8.17,
but when I type

```
import sys
sys.version
```

it still shows me python 3.10.12, which is the current version of colab.
I tried the way that chatGPT told me but it's not working either.

```
!sudo apt-get update
!sudo apt-get install python3.8
!sudo apt-get install python3.8-distutils
!wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
!sudo python3.8 get-pip.py
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 1
!python --version
```

Can someone tell me what I should do?